# Autohotkey, putting "D89dl" at the end of a sentence doesn't work as intended

Tags: autohotkey

I have a Autohotkey script that puts "D89dl" at the end of a sentence everytime I press Enter, but using it with a AutoCorrect script it doesn't work as it should. Let's say you type "dont", it then would look like this "don't" instead of "don't.". Something is blocking it but I'm not sure what it is, I've been trying for months now.

Here are the scripts:

```
enter::
send,D89dl{Enter}
Return

#Hotstring EndChars -()[]{}:;'"/\,.?!`n `t
::dont::don't
```

I would be VERY thankful if anyone of you helps me with this.

Overall, do you know any other way instead of Autohotkey that puts "D89dl" at the end of a sentence?

Comment: you probably meant >"dont" instead of "don't"< ? 

however, i cant reproduc your problem, not to speak that "doesn't work" is not useful

Answer (score 1):

The easiest solution seems to be to use the `:*:` mode, which will trigger everytime the misspelled word is typed, without the need for *Hotstring EndChars*:

```
:*:dont::don't
```

Instead of using *Enter*, I suggest you use a special combination of keys that enter the string *D89dl* and then press Enter. Use a modifier like ctrl or alt and another key. The reasoning is that the key *Enter* has very important functionality and should not be changed. Pressing that special combination is appropriate, given the very special function it does.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit hacky, but it should do the job (given that by "end of sentence" you actually meant pressing "Enter"):

```
~enter::
    Sleep, 100
    SendInput, {BS}D89dl{Enter}
Return

#Hotstring EndChars -()[]{}:;'"/\,.?!`n `t
::dont::don't
```